# How to only allow authenticated users on separate nginx?

Tags: nginx

I've been been working on a website with a pretty complex setup:

- 3 backend servers coded in java with netty running the main application
- A ngnix reverse-proxy doing load-balacing
- A seperate nginx webserver serving static content

As proof of concept, I want to have some important files like a big super secret document on the nginx-server serving static content but only allow authenticated users to access that file and I honestly have no clue to do it...

Comment: Sounds like you are asking a question as to how to handle authentication with `nginx`. Have you tried http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html ? That is what you will need since you have only one nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> [nginx auth module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html)

For more detailed usage [NGINX Authenticated User](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the second link, i already was able to implement it :D